# Unable to execute Update a record in SQLite database from Assets folder

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have SQLite database in assets folder. I want to use this database for reading(select) and writing(update) purpose. I am able to read the records but unable to update the records .

I am accessing the database using the following Code.

1. DBHelper class (To create the database in Read/Write Mode )
2. TestAdapter class
3. Activity class( To perform DB operations )

**DBHelper class code:**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    //destination path (location) of our database on device
    private static String DB_PATH = ""; 
    private static String DB_NAME ="";// Database name
    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
    private final Context mContext;

    public DBHelper(Context context,String DB_NAME) 
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);// 1? its Database Version
        this.DB_NAME=DB_NAME;
      //  DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";

        this.mContext = context;
        DB_PATH =  mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    }   
public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets

    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if(!mDataBaseExist)
    {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
       // this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}
    //Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Db Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }
     public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        //String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        String myPath = getWritableDatabase().getPath();
       mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
        return mDataBase;
    }
}
```

**2. TestAdapter class code**

```
public class TestAdapter {

    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private com.gre.db.DBHelper mDbHelper;
    public TestAdapter(Context context,String DB_NAME) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new com.gre.db.DBHelper(mContext,DB_NAME);
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
           mDb = mDbHelper.openDataBase();

          //  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return mDb;
    }
}
```

**3. Activity class to perform the DB Operations**

```
     TestAdapter adapter = new TestAdapter(this, "GREDB");
     SQLiteDatabase  db = adapter.open();
     String whereClause = where_clause="WORDID like '"+compare_wordid+"'";              
     ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
     cv.put("RATING",ref_rate);
     int n=db.update("WORD_A", cv, where_clause, null);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Rating updated to "+ref_rate,
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It is giving toast message that the rating is updated. But it is not updating in database.

Can any one please help me in this. Your help is really appreciated...

Thank you....

Comment: format your code first...

Comment: The asset folder is not writable. You have to copy the db to a writable folder, first. Possibly, your app private data folder.

Comment: Hi Der, I am copying into local memory to      DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/"; path